# UICollectionViewController Insets not adjusting and Scrolling properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to use a UICollectionViewControlller together with an inputAccessoryView for a chat page. I used the following code to try and scroll my collectionViewController to the last cell.

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0, self.messages.count - 1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

and for when keyboard is involved

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

@objc func handleKeyboardShow() {
    print("keyboard was called \(messages.count - 1)")
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0, messages.count - 1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working properly, the actual scrollable area seems to be too small as I can not even manually scroll to the latest cell when keyboard is open.

Here is an example video 
[LINK](https://youtu.be/_-Mslhpg0eY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Part of the `UICollectionView` went under your keyboard.

**Solution**

You need to increase bottom constraint between `UICollectionView` and it's superview on `keyboardDidShowNotification` and shrink it on `keyboardWillHideNotification`.

**Step by step**

- Save bottom constraint between `UICollectionView` and it's superview as a property in your `UIViewController` class
- Change it's height to keyboard size on `keyboardDidShowNotification`
- Change it's height to 0 on `keyboardWillHideNotification`

**If you subclassed CollectionViewController**

Change `scrollInset` property instead of bottom constraint.

`collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 300, 0);`

Instead of 300 set your keyboard's height that you got from notification.

**If you'll want to move from CollectionViewController and recreate behaviour later, here's the step by step process**

- Use `UIViewController` instead
- Add `UICollectionView` manually
- Add constrains manually, save bottom one as a property of the `UIViewController`'s subclass
- set `UICollectionView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to `self`
- Extend your `UIViewController` with protocol conformance (it was set by default for CollectionViewController)
- Repeat steps from

Comment: Only thing is I am using a CollectionViewController